# Best way to model Natural and Legal Customers all together

Tags: database-design

I want to design my project's data model but I have a problem in "Customer" section since I have two types of customers: Natural people and Legal entities
Which is the best way:

**Method 1**:
To have 3 tables like this:

```
    Customers:
    ID int not null (PK)
    CustomerType bit not null
    NaturalPersonID int (FK)
    LegalPersonID int (FK)

    NaturalPeople:
    ID int not null (PK)
    FirstName nvarchar(50) not null
    LastName nvarchar(50) not null
    NationalSecurityNumber char(10) not null
    ...

    LegalEntities:
    ID int not null (PK)
    CompanyName nvarchar(100) not null
    RegistrationNumber char(20) not null
    ...
```

which either NaturalPersonID or LegalPersonID is filled and the other is null and CustomerType shows the type of customer (Natural or Legal)

**Method 2**:
To have one table with all fields:

```
    ID int not null (PK)
    CustomerType bit not null
    FirstName nvarchar(50)
    LastName nvarchar(50)
    NationalSecurityNumber char(10)
    CompanyName nvarchar(100)
    RegistrationNumber char(20)
    ...
```

Which for each customers some fields are filled and the others are null

**Method 3**:
To have one table with some fields:

```
    ID int not null (PK)
    CustomerType bit not null
    FirstName nvarchar(50)
    LastName nvarchar(100)
    NationalSecurityNumber varchar(20)
    ...
```

Which the fields are filled for the natural customers naturally. But if the customer is a Legal one, we put data logically. For example CompanyName in the LastName field and RegistrationCode in the NationalSecurityNumber field and the FirstName field is null.

**Method 4**: 
any other way that I didn't think of and you can suggest

P.S. I'm implementing my database in MS SQL Server 2012

Comment: Take a look at the Party Data Model:
http://www.tdan.com/view-articles/5014/

Comment: How do you evaluate "best"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any of the approaches will have pros and cons, any of them would be applicable based on your application requirements and analysis. 
BTW I will prefer to use `Method 1` with some considerations:

1. `Customer` table will be the base table for `NaturalPeople` and
   `LegalEntities`, primary key of the Customer will be the primary key
   of the two others.
2. Customer table will contain: 
    
   Shared information of the two others, like customer-number, customer-type .... 
    
   Search key fields like customer-full-name(standard name), so you may set index on them
3. Avoid using a field for two different business values, like:

   > ```
   > The fields are filled for the natural customers naturally. 
   > But if the customer is a Legal one, we put data logically. For example 
   > CompanyName in the LastName field and RegistrationCode in
   > the NationalSecurityNumber field and the FirstName field is null.
   > ```

   Soon or late you will suffer if not separating the fields, due to violationg [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) (think that
   if National_Security_Number ) is a mandatory value for
   NaturalPeople and RegistrationCode is an optional value for
   LegalEntities. You can not set a unique key or mandatory check on the field.
4. Other entities (like accounts, Signs, Address ...) will having
   reference only to the Customer table.
5. You will need to implement a simple search on Customer table and an
   advanced search for legal and natural customers.

Comment: And if a have an entity that can be the both LegalEntities and NaturalPeople ? That is, an entity that can will derive from LegalEntities or NaturalPeople

Comment: Considering that I'm using the Method 1

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario I usually do one table `Customer` which has a PK and a discriminator column `CustomerType`, and two detail tables, one for Natural and one for Legal, but primary keys for those additional tables are the same as PK of the `Customers` table (similar to your method one, but without separate keys for two subtype tables). That way queries are simpler, you can enforce a 1:0 constraint between master and detail, there are no surrogate keys and data is normalized.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few words: do not forget that there is a potential relation between natural people and legal entities, where natural people belong to, or represent, legal entities. I would not hesitate to add a LegalEntityID FK to the NaturalPeople Table.

And, for the sake of simplicity, I would not name a foreign key field "NaturalPersonID" when this points to the "NaturalPeople" table. Call it NaturalPeopleID, it will make things clearer. Same thing for the "LegalPersonID" field. You could even limit your objects/tables denomination to "People" and "Entity", or "People" and " Institution" (this to avoid any confusion between your Entity object/table and the Entity concept in relational databases).

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 is a design pattern known as [class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance).

Method 2 is a design pattern known as [single-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/single-table-inheritance).

You can read up on these by visiting the tag and opening the info tab.

Method 3 has a name, which eludes me at the moment.

In your situation, I would pick method 1.

In method 1, you've followed the pattern pretty closely.  The one thing I'd suggest you consider is shared primary key.  Class table inheritance and shared primary key work well together.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table party_type (
  id serial primary key,
  description text not null unique
);

insert into party_type ('description') values
('Organization'),
('Individual'),
('Automated Agent');

create table party (
  id serial primary key,
  party_type_id int not null references party_type(id),
  organization_name text null,
  last_name text null,
  first_name text null,
);

insert into party (party_type_id, organization_name) values (1, 'Acme, Inc');
insert into party (party_type_id, last_name, first_name) values (2 'Doe', 'John');

create table role_type (
  id serial primary key,
  description text not null unique
);

insert into role_type ('description') values
('Customer'),

create table party_role (
  party_id int not null references party(id),
  role_type_id int not null references party_role_type(id),
  primary key (party_id, role_type_id)
);

/* add both parties as customers: */
insert into party_role values (1, 1);
insert into party_role values (2, 1);

create table identifier_type (
  id serial primary key,
  description text not null unique
);

insert into identifier_type ('description') values
('Social Security Number'),
('Registration Number');

create table party_identifier (
  party_id int not null references party(id),
  identifier_type_id int not null references identifier_type(id),
  id_number text not null,
  primary key (party_id, identifier_type_id)
);

insert into party_identifier values
(1, 2, 'some company reg number'),
(2, 1, 'some ssn')
```